# Delphi RAD Server - write Log into Server Console

Tags: logging, delphi-10.4.2

when Using RAD Server in Development Mode there is a Console that writes every Request every Function and so on.
Is it Posible to use this Console as a Debug console.
I Would like to throw some Exeptionmessages into taht console while coding but I can't find anything on that topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import Unit `EMS.ResourceAPI` into your uses

than use following code to write a Debug line

```
TEMSEndPointEnvironment.Instance.LogMessage('Your Debugmessage');
```

It also works in Production Mode. To use it activate debugfile in EmsServer.ini